# Timer stops every time the phone sleeps

Tags: android, timer

I'm creating this incredibly simple app, since I'm just starting with Android and I have no experience with Java what so ever. Anyhow, all I have is a timer and a button. Obviously the button starts the timer which counts down from 60 ( 1 minute ) and then vibrates when it's done. All worked fine up until the point I decided to press the lock screen button to put the phone to sleep. I found out that the timer in my app stops going until I unlock the phone. This also happens if I set the auto sleep time to less than 60 seconds and the phone falls asleep on it's own. My question is - how can I have that chronometer running even when the screen is not active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this using [`BroadCastRecievers`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for system-calls. ([Related Helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063382/how-to-handle-sleep-mode-enter-in-android))

You can also play off the [life-cyles](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) of the `Activity` using the [`PowerManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

---

Example using `PowerManager`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!isScreenOn) {
        // The screen has been locked
        // Continue your timer
    }
}
```